# Altering Query expression post creation

Tags: c#, query-expressions

I am trying to create a new query, then based on certain conditions edit and add to it. I do not know how to do the functions written in brackets []

```
/* Create the query */
var query = from quote in Query() 
where quote.documentNum = document_Input
select quote;

// Now change the sort field
query = filter.sort == SortFied.quote ? [alter the query function to sort by documentNum<string>] : [alter the query function to sort by enteredData<DateTime?>]

// Now change the sort direction
query = filter.sortDir == SortDirection.Ascending ? [alter the query to sort in an Ascending order] : [alter the query to sort in an Descending order]
```

These are just two conditions having to be added afterwards.The aim of adding it afterwards is to avoid duplicate code for each possible condition.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @SILENT [alter the query function to sort by documentNum<string>]. That is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming something like this.

```
var query = Query().Where(x => x.documentNum == document_Input);
query = filter.sortDir == SortDirection.Ascending ? query.OrderBy(x => filter.sort == SortFied.quote ? x.documentNum : x.enteredData) : query.OrderByDescending(x => filter.sort == SortFied.quote ? x.documentNum : x.enteredData);
```

You could further reduce code duplication by using delegates.

Comment: Just testing it out now with join statements. Will let you know soon.

Comment: Your solution did work partially, we run a custom LinqToProgress4GL query engine. I tried it out with a list and work just fine, but running it through the query engine failed. So ultimately your solution was correct.